# Atomic update statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

In many cases I need to obtain a unique identifier from a number series in SQL Server. What I have then is a table that contains a number series name, a min value, a max value and the current value.

```
Series        Min        Max        Current
-------------------------------------------
Testseries    1          999        23
```

Now I'd use the `UPDATE ... OUTPUT` statement to safely increment and output the current value. All other approaches (for example: `UPDATE` current and then `SELECT` are bound to cause race conditions sooner or later).

Now I found out there's the following syntax:

```
DECLARE @newId INT
UPDATE Numberseries
SET
    @newId = Current += 1
WHERE
    Series = '...'
```

This would work as at any point I'd only be updating one single row, as `Series` is the primary key.

My question is: Will this also be an atomic operation like the `UPDATE ... OUTPUT` statement so that two clients do not get the same value in simultaneous calls?

Comment: Read about [Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx). SQL Server supports this kind of action natively...

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately the customer is still on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks - I forgot.

Comment: You might create a numbers table (just plain numbers from 1 to X from where you point to the row this ID  belongs to... Just pick out the lowest number which is not yet bound to a row of your table. This should at least lead to concurrency errors if two processes cross each other...

Comment: It looks pretty thread safe to me. I can't definitively show that the assignment of the variable and the update are in a single transaction, but I have run a test looping the update and assignment, then inserting the variable into a new table. I ran this in 5 different windows, after 10,000,000 executions I still hadn't hit a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a table as `UPDATE`s are actually not atomic (at least on some DBS)! You can get away with it if you `INSERT` used values and have a `UNIQUE`-constraint on that value; you will have to retry-after-collision.

The real solution is to use a `SEQUENCE` - that's what they were made for.

Comment: Unless you are on a RDBMS that does not support sequences - as I said above.